# vscode not showing object more than 3 nests deep in terminal window/output

Tags: javascript, nested

I tried to print a multi-nested object or array to my vscode terminal window and vscode output. My result is a simplified version of what I was trying to print where a generic array/object is shown for anything deeper than 3 layers of nesting.
Is there a way to turn off that setting so I can see exactly what is in there?
Is there a way to format how my terminal window displays results in general?

```
let nestedObj1 = [1,{23:{3:4,3:{5:6,7:{3:4,5:{5:1}}}}}]
let nestedArray = [1,2,3,4,[1,2,2,4,2,[3,[4,[5,[1,3,2,3,[1,2,3,4]]]]]]]
console.log(nestedObj1,'\n',nestedArray)
```

Answer (score 12):

It's probably easiest to see nested values [in the interactive JS debugger in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging). If you can't do that for whatever reason, a trick to show all the deeply nested values would be to `console.log` the value after using `JSON.stringify` to transform the entire structure into a string. In your case, you could do:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(nestedObj1, null, 2))
```

The `null` and `2` arguments control how the JSON is formatted when it is serialized.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!